# Concurrent programming - Is it necessary to manually lock files that multiple processes will be accessing?

Tags: c, concurrency, process, fork

I know for pthreads, if they're modifying the same variables or files, you can use `pthread_mutex_lock` to prevent simultaneous writes.

If I'm using `fork()` to have multiple processes, which are editing the same file, how can I make sure they're not writing simultaneously to that file?

Ideally I'd like to lock the file for one writer at a time, and each process would only need to write once (no loops necessary). Do I need to do this manually or will UNIX do it for me?

Comment: `write` is always safe. If you use `stdio` functions, you need to take care of buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you have to do it manually.  There are certain guarantees on the atomicity of each write, but you'll still need to synchronize the processes to avoid interleaving writes.  There are a lot of techniques for synchronizing processes.  Since all of your writers are descendants of a common process, probably the easiest thing to do is to pass a token on a common pipe.  Before you fork, create a pipe and write a single byte into it.  Any time a process wants to write to the file, it will do a blocking read on the pipe.  If it gets a byte, then it proceeds to write to the file.  When it is done, it writes a byte back into the pipe.  If any other process wants to access the file, it will block on the pipe read until the other process is done writing.  This is often simpler than using a semaphore, which is another excellent technique.

Comment: Bottom line: don't use flock and fcntl, use some IPC instead (as suggested in this answer, I'd prefer more explicit semaphore) - it is generally much more reliable.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use a semaphore, I didn't realize they could be applied to processes as well.